# Aligning components in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, user-interface, android-relativelayout

|--Button 1--|

|-Button 2-|

Using RelativeLayout how do I align Button 2's width to match that of Button 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/A"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dip"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="--Button1--" />

<Button
        android:id="@+id/B"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/A"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Button2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/A"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/A"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
```

Try the above inside your `RelativeLayout`

Comment: I tried this before and it didn't work. That's why I posted this question. Anyways thanks for trying @Varun.

Comment: Sorry @Varun, I had my Button's layout_width set to "fill_parent", that's why I didn't get what I wanted. You are correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for should be [layout_alignRight](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_alignRight). This would align your `View`s right edge to the give anchors right edge.

Answer (score -1):

If you want Button 2 to be dependent on Button 1, then there is no way (best of my knowledge) to do so. However, if you are designing a dynamic layout, you can do so programatically.